# how to navigate to redux route at app start

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I have a selected items id persisted in localStorage. When the app starts I'd like to navigate to a route and use the id as route param.

Does react-router support that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app starts you set history object to router. You can use this object(history) to navigate.

```
browserHistory.push('/some/path');
```

If you use redux you can check this module https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux